# Drag and drop lists - multiple items with same priority

Tags: user-interface, drag-and-drop, user-experience

Initially, I had the following requirements:

1. There are 2 lists with items. The user needs to be able to move the items from one list into the other.
2. Each item needs to have a priority.

[image]I've implemented the following solution:

The user can drag and drop the items and I'm also keeping track of their priority. For example, in List1, Item1 has priority 1 and Item2 has priority 2 and so on. In List2, there is just Item4 with priority 1.

So this solution covers all the requirements.

The problem is that now there is a new requirement: **multiple items can have the same priority**.

So I can have Item1 and Item2 with priority 1 and Item3 with priority 2.

Can this current solution be adapted to this new requirement? I did think about it but wasn't able to find a solution.

Or is there a completely different approach that is more suitable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first pattern this problem made me think of was the Animation/Build Order panel in Keynote. In that panel you can give items unique positions or group with others so animations play at the same time. I feel that UX can work the same here kind of.

Essentially in the UI you could have items with the same priority "grouped".

[image: Items grouped by priority]

Just as important is the experience while dragging. You need to have UI to clearly tell the user what the result will be when they release the drag.

- Am I creating a unique priority for this item?
- Or am I grouping this with another?

Keynote does this with a underline/border style if I remember correctly. When dragging/dropping it is pretty common to use a dashed outline to show the resulting position. For example,

[image: UI while dragging prioritized items]

One final question you'd need to address – Is there a priority inside the priority groups? In other words, when grouped in a priority does the order of those items matter?